# Why is nothing written to output.txt in this example from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this in a batch file and nothing is put into output.txt on both Win7 and XP:

IF EXIST %systemdrive%\Test.exe (echo Success: %systemdrive%\Test.exe still exists) else (echo Bug: %systemdrive%\Test.exe file deleted) >> output.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are redirecting the output of the if, rather than of the echo. Try:

```
IF EXIST %systemdrive%\Test.exe (
    echo Success: %systemdrive%\Test.exe still exists >> output.txt
) else (
    echo Bug: %systemdrive%\Test.exe file deleted >> output.txt
)
```

Comment: This works, but I still don't get why the way I was doing it works with a shorter .exe name and then it doesn't when the .exe name gets longer.

Comment: Good question. The long version you posted in your other comment works fine for me.

Comment: Lame, I used your example as a work-around and it's working great ... not sure why Microsoft is so dumb sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It should, I just ran that and it produced output.txt. Are you sure you're looking in the active directory?

Comment: You're right, I actually changed the name from what I had so as not to give away what I am working on. It appears that if it's this instead then it doesn't work: IF EXIST %systemdrive%\SZWindowSensorTest.exe (echo Success: %systemdrive%\SZWindowSensorTest.exe still exists) else (echo Bug: %systemdrive%\SZWindowSensorTest.exe file deleted)>>output.txt